# How to do Text query from Ignite

Tags: c#, sql, ignite

I have the following code

```
public IImmutableList<T> Find<T>(string text) where T : class, new()
{
    IImmutableList<T> ret = new List<T>(0).ToImmutableList() as IImmutableList<T>;

    var (name, _) = Utility.GetDatasetAttributes<T>();
    var cache = _client.GetCache<Guid, T>(name);
    var textQuery = new TextQuery(typeof(FinancialGroup), text);


    var data = cache.Query(textQuery)
        .GetAll()
        .Select(x => x.Value)
        .ToImmutableList<T>() as IImmutableList<T>;

    ret = data;


    return ret;
}
```

I'm using the following class:

```
public class FinancialGroup: ICacheRow  //,IBinarizable
    {
        [QuerySqlField(IsIndexed = true)] public Guid RowKey => Key;

        public Guid Key { get; set; }
        [QuerySqlField(IsIndexed= true), QueryTextField()] public string Name { get; set; }
        [QuerySqlField(IsIndexed= true)] public int Type { get; set; }
        [QuerySqlField(IsIndexed= true), QueryTextField()] public string Number { get; set; }
        [QuerySqlField(IsIndexed= true)] public Guid ImageKey { get; set; }
        [QuerySqlField()] public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
        [QuerySqlField()] public DateTime ModifiedOn { get; set; }
    }
```

But it does not compile at all even though I followed the instructions given here: 
https://ptupitsyn.github.io/Getting-Started-With-Apache-Ignite-Net-3-Sql/

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: the textQuery cannot be passed to Query(). it needs either ScanQuery(), FieldQuery() or other but not TextQuery(). even though the link i mentioned clearly says i can pass by that's not possible. any ideas on how can i do that?

Comment: It's strange, `Query()` accepts `QueryBase` and `TextQuery` is `QueryBase`. Can you provide a screenshot of an error?